# Do we need the tag "physics"?

Tags: discussion, tags

We've got questions tagged with "physics".

If the physics of the question is real and answerable by real physics, we can abstract it and pass it to physics.SE.

If the physics is virtual ( for example : portal ). The question would be closed by physics.SE guys because that is not real. We have a perfect example of this case, which is a [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/13923/would-portal-style-portals-transmit-gravity) being migrated to physics.SE and got closed.

If we want an [answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4272/physics-of-iron-man-curious) out of a virtual technology ( for example: star gate ), we could end up in some "magic" explanation or explanation without real world physics support. So these answers have nothing to deal with "physics"

Answer (score 11):

The tag [physics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physics) is about the physics of a fictional universe, like [languages](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/languages) is about languages in a fictional universe, [magic](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic) is about magic in a fictional universe and so on.

I don't see why there shouldn't be a [physics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physics) tag. It's not about real-world physics, any more than [magic](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic) is about real-world magic. I've added a big description to the tag wiki, for the 0.0000001% of users who read the tag wikis.