# Do we need [science]?

Tags: discussion, tags

The [science](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science) tag has 87 questions and 16 followers, but it isn't clear to me what it's supposed to be used for. The tag wiki does not help much:

> Stories about science, or questions about the science of a story

Questions about real-world science are off-topic, and I don't know why we would need a tag to designate stories that are about science specifically, or how we would judge that.

That leaves questions about in-universe science, like what exactly happens if you cross the streams in ghostbusters, perhaps.

I propose either changing the tag wiki to say that it's for explanations of in-universe science, or nuking the tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting from [Gilles's excellent answer](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/742/31394) to a related question:

> The tag [physics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physics) is about the physics of a fictional universe, like [languages](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/languages) is about languages in a fictional universe, [magic](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic) is about magic in a fictional universe and so on.
>
> I don't see why there shouldn't be a [physics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physics) tag. It's not about real-world physics, any more than [magic](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic) is about real-world magic.

Science, like [magic](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic), [aliens](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aliens), [spaceship](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spaceship)s, [physics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physics), [astronomy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/astronomy), etc., is a common enough trope in SF/F literature to be worth its own tag, provided we make clear what types of question would be on-topic in this tag.

However, I definitely agree that the current tag wiki for [science](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science) isn't good enough. I suggest the following tag wiki excerpt (thanks to  [@Mazura](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9219/31394)):

> For questions about the fictitious in-universe science found in works of speculative fiction. Questions purely concerning real-world science are off-topic.

... and the following tag wiki (based heavily on @Gilles's tag wiki for [physics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physics)):

> Use this tag if your question is about the fictional science found in the universe of a work of science fiction or fantasy. Note that this site is about fiction, not about real-world science. Expect answers based on internal consistency or author fiat ('Word of God').
>
> If your question is about:
>
> - how the in-universe science relates to real-world science, ask here, but do not necessarily expect answers from experts on real-world science.
> - real-world science, your question is off-topic here. You might consider asking on one of the [science-based Stack Exchange sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites#science).
>
> Please see [this discussion thread](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7364/what-is-our-actual-policy-on-science-questions) for more detail about our policy on science questions.

Comment: I guess physics and astronomy aren't science!

Comment: @CreationEdge They are, and I think those tags are also fine provided they have clear usage guidance (as [tag:physics] does). I guess there's an argument for getting rid of [tag:science] and replacing it by more specific tags such as [tag:physics], [tag:astronomy], [tag:chemistry], etc., but then those tags might not have many questions each.

Comment: I dunno, I remain skeptical. Has anyone proven physics is science?

Comment: I had to look up *author fiat*.

Comment: @Mazura Er ... so did I. Most of that tag wiki came from Gilles. Edited slightly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems in your post the [science](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science) tag, you're implying that the best use of the tag is for explaining the in-universe science is a work of fiction.

However in much the same way that we don't need a tag for [plot-explanation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plot-explanation) because it should be implied for the majority of questions about plot,  I feel the same holds over with [science](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science).

Comment: Could the person who disagrees,  explain?

Comment: I disagree, sorry. For my explanation, see my answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

New tag description:

> For questions about the **fictitious in-universe science** found in works of fiction. Questions purely concerning **real-world science** are off-topic.

Comment: Thanks; added to my answer.